# Is it compulsory to make a folder before creating react app

Tags: reactjs

why cannot create react app directly in a directory before going in a particular folder

```
D:\>create-react-app ananya

Creating a new React app in D:\ananya.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts...

npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...e"},"devDependencies"'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\sethi\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-08-24T05_53_19_688Z-debug.log

Aborting installation.
  npm install --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react-scripts has failed.

Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting ananya/ from D:\
Done.

D:\>
```

Comment: No. `ananya` itself is project folder. The problem is something else.  Check the logs / paste here - C:\Users\sethi\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2019-08-24T05_53_19_688Z-debug.log

Comment: Also check this - https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app

Comment: @ravibagul91 yes,i know ananya is project folder but my question is "Is it COmpulsory to make a folder before making 'ananya' project folder" so that ananya will become subfolder

Comment: No. It is not compulsary.

Answer (score 2):

You can create directly in your D:\ directory. Error is nothing to do with the folder.
You just need to clear your npm cache and try again. Run the below command in your cmd.

```
npm cache clean --force
```

You can also clean the cache by deleting all the content in this folder manually : `

> C:\Users\*YOUR_USER_NAME*\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache

`

Answer (score 2):

You can also try

```
npx create-react-app ananya
```

This will create the project folder `ananya` and have the project files in it.

OR

```
npx create-react-app .
```

This will create the project in the current folder.

**Note:** The current folder **must** be empty. Project name will be the **folder name.** So you have to properly name your folder before executing.

Comment: which current folder

Comment: Current working folder which terminal is opened at. It your case it's **D:\>**
Don't use `npx create-react-app .` on the D: drive itself. Remember the `.` will create all the project files right at the location you execute the command.